# how to handle too many endpoints azure functions

Tags: go, azure-functions

I have an application written in Go, Gin, and libpq.
This app has too many endpoints, and I am having problems.
I deployed the application on azure functions, the problem is that for each endpoint I need to create a folder with the ENDPOINT NAME + the function.json file, thus generating my endpoint..
the problem is that I have many endpoints, is there any way to register all my endpoints in just one function.json file?

My project is divided like this:

routes:
routes.go
main.go

my main.go looks like this:

```html
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/guilherm5/brapoio/routes"
)

func main() {

    //gin.New torna o gin mais maleavel criando uma nova instancia do gin
    Router := gin.New()
    Router.Use(gin.LoggerWithWriter(gin.DefaultErrorWriter))

    //routes é um package em que se encontra somente minhas rotas e os verbos http

    //tem toda minha parte de configuração
    routes.ConfiguracaoSistema(Router)
    routes.ConfiguracaoModulo(Router)
    routes.ModuloSistema(Router)
    routes.ArvoreMenu(Router)
    routes.ModuloArvoreMenu(Router)

    //tem toda minha parte de Usuario
    routes.Usuario(Router)
    routes.EmpresaUsuario(Router)
    routes.CampoTabelaUsuario(Router)
    routes.ProgramaUsuario(Router)
    routes.FuncionalidadeProgramaUsuario(Router)
    routes.TabelaUsuario(Router)
    routes.ParametroFiltroTabelaUsuario(Router)
    //meu servidor de autenticação
    routes.JWTAutentication(Router)

    handler := azfunc.HTTPHandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        setupRouter().ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })

    azfunc.Main(handler)

    listenAddr := ":1000"

    if val, ok := os.LookupEnv("FUNCTIONS_CUSTOMHANDLER_PORT"); ok {
        listenAddr = ":" + val
    }

    Router.Run(listenAddr)

}
```

my PACKAGE ROUTES (IT IS A SEPARATE PACKGE FROM THE MAIN) is like this

routeS:
campotabela.go:
package routes

```html
import(
"github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
"github.com/guilherm5/brapoio/controllers"
)

func UserTableField(c *gin.Engine) {
c.GET("/api/fieldTable", controllers.GetFieldTableUsuario())
c.GET("/api/campoTable/:ID", controllers.GetCampoTableaUsuarioID())
}

then I have other FILES inside routes
configsystem.go :
                        package routes

import(
"github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
"github.com/guilherm5/brapoio/controllers"
)

func SystemConfiguration(c *gin.Engine) {
c.GET("/api/config", controllers.GetSystemConfig())
c.GET("/api/config/:ID", controllers.GetSystemID())
c.POST("/api/config", controllers.NewConfigSystem())
}
```

I have 10 more of these files, with different names..

how do i have just one function.json file and register all my endpoints in it?